# PCIe mode in chip-to-chip communication

Tags: pcie

In my understanding, the most common PCIe usage is in computer systems which involves a processor host communicating with various endpoints through the PCIe tree topology. In this scenario, we will have the host configured in root complex mode, and the switch configured in bridge mode, and finally the devices configured to an end-point mode.

But what if today the system only has chip-to-chip communication and they adopt the PCIe communication protocol, while at the same time, both chips have their own processor? In this usage model, which mode (RP/EP) should the PCIe controller act as? Who should initiate the enumeration?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the system architecture.

If you truly have two CPU sockets, you might want to either use a peer-to-peer protocol like HT, QPI or UPI, or connect the PCIe domains using a Non-Transparent Bridge (NTB).

If you have a hierarchical relationship between the CPUs, then it is clear which CPU should start up first, and release the other from reset.